# How to prevent ARKit collecting dynamic objects which will make the anchor point incorrectly adjusted

Tags: swift, arkit, arworldmap

I'm developing an app that load ARWorldMap and all the anchor in it. 
I found that if I scanned some dynamic objects (like people, display, doors open/close ) and saving WorldMap, Next time when i load this WorldMap the anchors will be adjusted to the wrong position.

So how can i prevent ARKit collecting datas?
if i stop ARSession camera will stop callback , it's not make sense for user.

Is there any solutions?